# How can I make one edit button work for multiple rows in a dynamic table with Angular7

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a update functionality for my dynamic table. I want to make the edit button work for multiple rows. Not just work for one row. How can I do that?

Now, this functionality work for the row that user clicks and the data can be updated successfully with Reactive Form. 
Then, I have tried to get the index in my ts file but I can't make it. Is that the correct way to achieve this or I am on the wrong way?

app.html

```
<form [formGroup]="tableForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Relationship</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of customer; index as i">
      <td>
        <input *ngIf="checkRow === i" formControlName="firstName">
        <ng-container *ngIf="checkRow !== i">{{data.firstName}}</ng-container>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input *ngIf="checkRow === i" formControlName="lastName">
        <ng-container *ngIf="checkRow !== i">{{data.lastName}}</ng-container>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input *ngIf="checkRow === i" formControlName="Relationship">
        <ng-container *ngIf="checkRow !== i">{{data.Relationship}}</ng-container>
      </td>
      <ng-container *ngIf="data.Relationship === 'employee'">
        <td>
          <button *ngIf="!showEdit" (click)="edit(i)"> Edit </button>
          <button type="submit" *ngIf="showEdit"> Save </button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

app.ts

````
export class AppComponent {

  customer: Array<any> = [
    { lastName: 'Leo', firstName: 'Fe', Relationship: 'employee' },
    { lastName: 'Leo', firstName: 'Cu', Relationship: 'spouse'},
    { lastName: 'Leo', firstName: 'Mn', Relationship: 'child'}, 
    { lastName: 'AC', firstName: 'V',  Relationship: 'employee'},
    { lastName: 'Presley', firstName: 'Mn', Relationship: 'employee'},
    { lastName: 'Presley', firstName: 'Ds', Relationship: 'spouse'}
  ];

  public tableForm: FormGroup;

  public showEdit: boolean = false;
  public checkRow: any;

  constructor( 
    private fb: FormBuilder, 
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['',],
      lastName: ['',],    
      Relationship: ['',],     
    })
  }

  edit(i) {
    this.showEdit = true;
    this.checkRow = i;

    this.tableForm.get('firstName').setValue(this.customer[this.checkRow].firstName);
    this.tableForm.get('lastName').setValue(this.customer[this.checkRow].lastName);
    this.tableForm.get('Relationship').setValue(this.customer[this.checkRow].Relationship);
  }

  submit() {

    this.customer[this.checkRow].firstName = this.tableForm.value.firstName;
    this.customer[this.checkRow].lastName = this.tableForm.value.lastName;
    this.customer[this.checkRow].Relationship = this.tableForm.value.Relationship;

    this.showEdit = false;
    this.checkRow = null;
  }

}




```
````

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "make one edit button work for multiple rows".  Perhaps you can clarify that.  But I see that in your code each row is mapping to the same set of form controls.  Usually you would want each row to have its own set of form controls.  You can do this using `FormArray` and nested `FormGroup`s.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. From now, when I click the edit button. It only allows one row to be editable. But I want it to be editable for multiple rows. Is that more clear? On the form control, I didn't user form array because I can't make the data to be group right now so maybe I will modify in the future if I solve the edit button first. Thanks.